# Client side scripting to make changes in a file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, client-side

Is there any client-side script that would be able to make changes to a file on the hosts computer? (Intention stated below)

I am creating a packaged app for chrome which can show some online data, and make it available even when offline.
There is a certain thing, for e.g. 'a webpage' i want to show/store (but i cannot get/read its contents due to it being on different origin). To show when online, i can use iframe, but am unable to preserve it for offline.

So i thought i could make an appcache (manifest within the application package) which will cache the file, and on press of an update button a script would run which would make some change to the manifest which would force the cached resource to be reloaded.

I searched a lot, but no results.

Any suggestions as to how it can be done. Or any other way to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so.  This could be a huge security problem if it existed.

If you had to, you could send an ajax request to the server to create a file it creates with the current prices, and add it to the appcache file.

Comment: Correct, JS is hands off the file system (for security reasons)  If you want to modify local files, you need a plugin of some sort.

Comment: Oh really?
Can you cite an example if you have any at the top of your mind, how this might pose a security threat? Actually in my application I just want to get/store/display gold rates and stock quotes. Just needed the part for that. Will let that part remain network only otherwise.

Comment: @Limey Any other way to accomplish the goal? & PitaJ your comment was in relation to client side modifying the code or the intention in general?

Comment: @playmaker:  hmmm what could a hacker do if he had access to write or read any file on your local system using JS just by going to his website.......thats a BIG problem!

Comment: @Limey Oh alright, I thought you were referring to the intention of storing, and that not being possible. -------------- Guys please just think and tell me if there is any other workaround possible

Comment: @Playmaker:  if you are looking at just storing small, teenie, tiny bits of data like a current stock price, why not just store in the session?  Or, if it really has to be local, store as a cookie.  Overall, If i was looking at stock prices, i would used ajax just to pull from the server side the current price.

Comment: Yeah mate, the problem is my server won't be supplying this data. And being cross-origin I am unable to read the contents. Can't find a free api which will send the qoutes or rates in response. :(

Comment: There used to be nice free web services that you could call to get the current price of a stock (been a long time since I have had to do something it)  you try yahoo?  maybe it has a free service?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to another SO quesitob that has a list of APIs you could use to get your stock price.

[Webservice to get stock quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773461/webservice-to-get-stock-quotes)